# Unify values in Python PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, pyxml

I'm an intermediary in Python, and recently I am developing some projects for the company that I work using Pandas to manipulate and automate some spreadsheets in Excel.

One of the spreadsheets contains 4800 values of multiples companies that are owing to my company, and what I need to do with the code is to send an e-mail to the company that are owing with the value that she owes, and some values are out of order, but are from the same company, example below:

```
COMPANY | VALUE
COMPANY 1 | US$ 1400
COMPANY 2 | US$ 2200
COMPANY 1 | US$ 900
COMPANY 3 | US$ 1500
```

What I need to do and I'm having issues, is to formulate a code that read those columns even out of order, unify the lines that are from the same company to send an e-mail to her, example below:

```
 Hello COMPANY 1! You owe US$ 2300, according to these lines below:

    COMPANY 1 | R$ 1400
    COMPANY 1 | R$ 900
```

Obs: I'm using smtplib to send the e-mails.

The code to send the e-mails automatically I already have, I just need to know how can I make the program read the spreadsheet and get the values of the same company together to send by e-mail, here's my entire code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib

list_months = ['Spreadsheet 1']

# localize the columns and lines
owing_clients = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\youruserhere\Documents\Owing Clients.xlsx')

# change these as per use
your_email = "email"
your_password = "password"

# establishing connection with gmail
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.ehlo()
server.login(your_email, your_password)

# getting the names and the emails
names = owing_clients['Debtor Name']
emails = owing_clients['Email']
values = owing_clients['Value']
debtorcode1 = owing_clients['Debtor Code']

# iterate through the records
for i in range(len(emails)):

    # mark the name, email and value of the debtor:
    name = names[i]
    email = emails[i]
    value = values[i]
    debtorcode1 = debtorcode[i]

    # the message to be emailed
    message = f"Subject: Debt\nHello {name}, you owe {value}, your debtor code is {debtorcode1}"
    # send email
    server.sendmail(your_email, [email], message)
    print(f'Your e-mail was successfully send!')

# Close the server
server.close()
```

Here's the spreadsheet for example:

[image: Spreadsheet example]

I can execute the entire code and he sends the e-mails, but he sends one by one, and you know that is like the corporate bureaucracy, my company doesn't want one by one, they want me to unify all the values of a single company and send it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should look into using a 'group by' operation. For each email identifying a company, group the different corresponding lines and write a mail using the group data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got the idea, but I don't get it how to apply her into the code. Can you tell me more about this? I've never used this "group by", I've searched for it but it has confused me more by now, because I dont get it how am I gonna apply this to the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Preparing data:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {

    'Value': [1400, 2200, 900, 1500], 

    'Company': ['C1', 'C2', 'C1', 'C3'],

}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

```
    Value   Company
0   1400    C1
1   2200    C2
2   900     C1
3   1500    C3
```

### Groupby

```
df.groupby('Company').sum()
```

### Output

```
    Value
Company     
C1  2300
C2  2200
C3  1500
```

Comment: Thank you so much, didn't have any Idea of that resolution, you helped a lot.